# Unsecured images not loading in android web view through secured network connection

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

When I try to load unsecured image (http://.....) in web view,  it does't load that image when my device is connected to secure wifi connections.   But , when I connected to mobile data it loads that unsecured image. And also secured images loads in all type of network connection.

```
 String htmlContent = "<img height=\'100px\' width=\'100px\' src='http://.....'> </img>";
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(false);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
    }

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", htmlContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");//No I18N
```

By debugging it is found that HTTP error occurs in web view client. But, I can't able to find the root cause of that http error. How to overcome that network related image loading issue in web view ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't you just replace `src='http://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-1.jpg'` with `src='https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-1.jpg'` ?

Comment: try webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);

Comment: @Signo, I tried with 'https:// ' url of that image it does't works.

Comment: @FaisalNaseer, I already tried with setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW) ( in source code also you can see). But it does't works for me.

Comment: @sathish Try with webView.loadUrl(url); instead of webView.loadDataWithBaseURL

Comment: @Nainal Thanks for reply. I tried with your answer. It throws ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED error.

Comment: @sathish Have you  provided the unsecured image url or the htmlContent string?

Comment: @Nainal, Yes. I tried with unsecured image url (http://). It works if my device connected to mobile data but not works if connected to secured wifi connection. In iOS app , the same url works fine.

Comment: Try adding this in your manifest:- <application>
        <meta-data android:name="android.webkit.WebView.EnableSafeBrowsing"
                   android:value="false" />
        ...
    </application>

Comment: @Nainal, EnableSafeBrowsing is false option does't work for me. It throws same ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED error.